# Add customer's card name field to the Stripe form on existing Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkout, stripe-payments

I have an existing Rails 4, Ruby 2 project with Stripe integrated with the form with 3 fields only - CVC, Card Number and Expiration Date. My problem is that I can't add 'name on card' field inside the form. I saw that all tutorials have examples with a custom form and some JavaScript but my form is not inside the project and I can't find where the fields CVC, Card Number etc. are being populated. Also there is no JavaScript anywhere which is for example in this tutorial - https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms but the Stripe/Checkout still works.

In users_controller.rb there is subscribe method:

```
def subscribe
  token = params[:stripeToken]
  subscription = params[:subscription]
  customer = current_user.stripe_customer_data

  subs = customer.subscriptions.all
  subs[:data].each do |sub|
    customer.subscriptions.retrieve(sub[:id]).delete
  end

  customer.subscriptions.create(
    plan: subscription,
    card: token,
    trial_end: current_user.subscription_expires.to_time.to_i
  )
  current_user.update_attribute(:subscription, subscription)
  current_user.update_attribute(:subscription_state, 'selected')

  @data = current_user.stripe_customer_data

  redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
end
```

In views/user/_subscrition.html.haml: (this is all from views and form that exists regarding Stripe/Checkout - there is no custom form that is being generated by Stripe/Checkout somehow):

```
.col-md-3
    = form_tag user_subscribe_path do
      = hidden_field_tag :subscription, 'monthly',
      = javascript_include_tag "https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js",
         :class => "stripe-button",
         :"data-key" => "#{STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}",
         :"data-label" => "Monthly Payment",
         :"data-panel-label" => "Pay {{amount}} monthly.",
         :"data-name" => Name",
         :"data-email" => "#{current_user.email}",
         :"data-description" => "Monthly",
         :"data-amount" => "29",
         :"data-image" => "#{image_path('image.png')}",
         :"data-allow-remember-me" => false
```

There are also some methods in a user model related to Stripe but I don't see that they are relevant to adding user input field inside the form so I will not add them unless it is required. What am I missing here and what is the way of adding a cardholder name input field to the form beside CVC, Expiration Date and Card Number? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find where the fields CVC, Card Number etc. are being populated ...

This is coming from https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js . You are passing in some options via data attributes like data-name and data-description and then checkout.js does its thing and creates the final form.

The beauty of checkout.js makes it easy to take payments though there are limited built-in options. See [configuration options here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-options)

You can validate against user ZIP though I don't believe you can use Stripe to validate against name on card, someone please correct me if I'm wrong on this one ;) so I'm guessing you want this for internal use.

FWIW, I'm doing something similar to what you're asking (in a PHP environment) by collecting the user's name via a regular form, then appending it to the description passed to checkout.js
eg

```
data-description=" <?php echo $payment_description .$customerName; ?>"
```

If you maintain an internal database with subscriber info, you could also save the name there and pair it with the cusotmer token.

Good luck!